# Tensorflow eager mode support for text summary

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, eager

I am trying to make a summary of a text using tensorflow with eager mode enabled, for this I am using this code:

```
writer = summary_ops_v2.create_file_writer('some_path', flush_millis=10000)
writer.set_as_default()

tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor("Some text")
meta = tf.SummaryMetadata()
meta.plugin_data.plugin_name = "text"

with summary_ops_v2.always_record_summaries():
   summary_ops_v2.generic(name="text", tensor=tensor)
```

but when reviewing tensorboard the event is created, but the text is not being saved ([Tensorboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK8De.png))

Try using `tf.make_tensor_proto` but it did not work either.

```
writer = summary_ops_v2.create_file_writer('some_path', flush_millis=10000)
writer.set_as_default()

tensor = tf.make_tensor_proto("Some text", dtype=tf.string)
meta = tf.SummaryMetadata()
meta.plugin_data.plugin_name = "text"

with summary_ops_v2.always_record_summaries():
   summary_ops_v2.generic(name="text", tensor=tensor)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might have been a bug. I updated to tensorflow 1.13.1 and the summaries started been displayed correctly.